# sendmail not delivering all email in 50 messages batches immediately

Tags: linux, sendmail, smtp, suse

I'm programmatically sending email to somewhere between 1 and 50 emails. The program is creating and handing off the emails and many are sent immediately. However, i frequently get some that are delayed several minutes and in larger batches delays in delivery of some for hours and i've even had one delivered a day later. Sendmail is handing off to Exchange and there's no issue with this handoff as evidenced by the (maybe 75%) that are delivered within the first couple of minutes. it's these outliers that take hours to get delivered i'm not sure how to fix.

anyone else seen this kind of issue and/or know how to resolve this issue?

Cheers!

Comment: Is Exchange configured to rate-limit? (Actually, is it configured *not* to rate-limit your sender IP address?)

Comment: Are you certain the problem is in sendmail? What have you tried to isolate and diagnose the problem?

Comment: Are you actually using the MTA called Sendmail, or an executable called /usr/sbin/sendmail provided by one of the many available MTAs (including Sendmail, but also postfix, exim, courier, and others).    The difference is significant because they all have their own queuing and re-sending strategies (which can also be tweaked in the config).  It's been a very long time since I used Sendmail MTA (I use postfix), so it's probably improved a bit in the last ~20 years, but it was S L O W.

Comment: BTW, you can tell /usr/sbin/sendmail to attempt to deliver all queued mail with `sendmail -q`.   AFAIK, `-q` works with the sendmail binary provided by all MTAs.

Comment: I find it really frustrating when someone voted down a question which is one it is obvious I known little or nothing about. It shows an unwillingness to help, coach, and or provide answers.. but i digress.

Sendmail is the utility i'm using for my interface. My guess is that it's the sendmail executable. My understanding is that the server is configured via postfilx to hand off to Exchange on port 25 (just found this out today). Now, it's pretty obvious i am not a mail expert here, which is why i'm asking for help.. but i suspect sendmail exe is handing off to postifx somehow.

Comment: I've issued the sendmail -q command (somewhere around lunch yesterday) and i still didn't receive an email until after 8PM last night. I read in another thread that this could be a limitation on port 25 (hosted in AWS) pointing to our Exchange (O365) server and if i convert it to port 587, it would eliminate the port 25 limit. Researching that with our linux team now.

Comment: Eric, there are at least three questions in these comments looking for clarification. While I haven't downvoted you, I could imagine someone might do so because of the continuing lack of information.

Comment: The `mailq` command should show you for every queued message a reason why it was delayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sendmail's default delivery mode forks sub process for every received message with "at once" delivery/relaying attempt. It may (temporarily) "overload" next hop server with multiple parallel especially in case of antispam checks.

Suggested fixes:

- **easiest:** introduce delays between sending messages (e.g. 1s) for above 5 emails batches
- tuning sendmail configuration above basic level (especially for one key destination)
- if you use low level SMTP library and can issue `VERB` (verbose) ESMTP command then your sending program may avoid sendmail forking and wait for end for initial delivery attept

Comment: Thanks AnFi. This is very helpful. I'm currently working with our Unix team to address this. Similar suggestion from them was to introduce a delay in the sending instead of all at once. This confirms their suggestion and I thank you for the info!